# Uncover proof symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer

In beamer if you make a proof like so:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
Not p.
\uncover<2->{Therefore not q.}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

it comes with a square in the bottom right corner. In my proof however I incrementally uncover the arguments. How can I make the square appear only when the last argument is uncovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\qedhere`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
Not p.
\uncover<2->{Therefore not q. \qedhere}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]